# PDO MSSQL fetches keys and row index

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I'm trying to get data using PHP and PDO from MSSQL. I do get data, but..

Better look.

That's my code:

```
$db = new PDO('dblib:host=sql-esk.prodnt;dbname=cd_clients', 'login', 'password');
$command = $db->prepare('SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON');
$command->execute();
$command = $db->prepare('SET ANSI_NULLS ON');
$command->execute();

$sth = $db->query("exec cp_list_tree_xml_test MAZER");

$data = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP);

print_r($data);
```

And that's what I get:
[image]

Every object fetched, consists of key=>value AND index=>value.
I don't need index=>value and I dont know where it comes from and why. Is it possible to fetch elememnts without index=>value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
$data = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN|PDO::FETCH_GROUP);
```

Comment: all inner objects became empty (

Comment: $data = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC|PDO::FETCH_GROUP);

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the following:

```
  $data = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

instead of :

```
  $data = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP);
```